# two similar functions, different results

Tags: c

My brain is in pain. I cannot figure what is happening here. I would pay if allowed the person with the best answer.

I have this Weight program for school and it allows user to input starting weight and than through a switch it calls various functions which are either allows user to gain weight or lose weight. Some functions return what I am expecting and some don't. These functions return what I expect  cakeGain(), hardWorkout(), mediumWorkout(), but I cant figure out why I am getting incorrect returns on runLoss(), burgerGain(), pizzaGain() and easyWorkout(). I cannot seem to figure out any big difference between the functions and I have tried all kinds of options. I was originally passing my weight variable by reference to all the functions and letting them change the value but my instructor did not want all the pointers.

This is not beautiful code and I have commented out some sections which I will fix later. I know a lot of my work is bad form (system calls etc.) but my instructor has not taught us alternative methods or does not care. This is still considered a beginner course. All I am curious on is why some functions work when others do not.

Thanks again,

Mike (I really appreciate all that take time from their schedules to help people like me out. I cannot wait for the day that I am competent enough to help out others).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define pause system ("pause")
#define cls system ("cls")
#define flush fflush(stdin)

//prototype functions here
void mainMenu(void);
char getUserChoice();
double enterWeight();
double runLoss(double usersWeight);
double burgerGain(double usersWeight);
double eatPizza(double usersWeight);
double eatCake(double usersWeight);
double hardWorkout(double usersWeight);
double mediumWorkout(double usersWeight);
double easyWorkout(double usersWeight);
//void weightChecker(double usersWeight);

int main() {
    //declare main variables here
    char userChoice = ' ';
    double usersWeight;


    do {
        userChoice = getUserChoice(); 

        switch (userChoice) {
                case'A': //get weight
                usersWeight = enterWeight();
                cls;
                printf("Your starting weight is: %dlbs.\n\n",usersWeight);
                break;
            case'B': //run
                usersWeight = runLoss(usersWeight);
                cls;
                printf("Your weight is now %d.\n", usersWeight);
                //weightChecker(usersWeight);
                break;
            case'C': //eat burger
                usersWeight = burgerGain(usersWeight);
                cls;
                printf("Your weight is now %d.\n", usersWeight);
                //weightChecker(usersWeight);
                break;
            case'D': //eat pizza
                usersWeight = eatPizza(usersWeight);
                cls;
                printf("Your weight is now %d.\n", usersWeight);
                //weightChecker(usersWeight);
                break;
            case'E': //eat cake
                usersWeight = eatCake(usersWeight);
                cls;
                printf("Your weight is now %d.\n", usersWeight);
                //weightChecker(usersWeight);
                break;
            case'F': //hard workout
                usersWeight = hardWorkout(usersWeight);
                cls;
                printf("Your weight is now %d.\n", usersWeight);
                //weightChecker(usersWeight);
                break;
            case'G': //medium workout
                usersWeight = mediumWorkout(usersWeight);
                cls;
                printf("Your weight is now %d.\n", usersWeight);
                //weightChecker(usersWeight);
                break;
            case'H': //easy workout
                usersWeight = easyWorkout(usersWeight);
                cls;
                printf("Your weight is now %d.\n", usersWeight);
                //weightChecker(usersWeight);
                break;
            case'I': //quit
                exit(0);

    }

    } while(userChoice != 'I');

    return 0;

} //end of main



char getUserChoice() {
    char result;
    do {
    mainMenu();
    scanf("%c", &result);
    flush;
    result = toupper (result);


    } while (result < 'A' || result > 'I');

    return result;

}

void mainMenu(void) {
    //cls;
    printf("A) \tEnter starting weight or change weight\n");
    printf("B) \tGo running\n");
    printf("C) \tEat Hamburgers\n");
    printf("D) \tEat pizza\n");
    printf("E) \tEat cake\n");
    printf("F) \tDo a hard workout\n");
    printf("G) \tDo a medium workout\n");
    printf("H) \tDo a easy workout\n");
    printf("I) \tQuit\n\n");
    printf("Enter your selection: ");

}

double enterWeight() {
    double startingWeight = 0.0;
    printf("Please enter your starting weight.\n");
    scanf("%i", &startingWeight);
    flush;

    return startingWeight;
}

double runLoss(double usersWeight) {
    double result;
    double milesRan = 0.0;
    double runMinus = 0.0;
    printf("How many miles did you run?\n");
    scanf("%i", &milesRan);
    flush;
    runMinus = milesRan * .005;
    result = usersWeight - runMinus;

    return result;
}

double burgerGain(double usersWeight) {
    double result;
    double hamburgersAte = 0.0;
    double hamburgerGain = 0.0;
    printf("How many hamburgers did you eat?\n");
    scanf("%i", &hamburgersAte);
    flush;
    hamburgerGain = hamburgersAte * .005;

    if (hamburgersAte > 2) {
        hamburgerGain = hamburgerGain + .5;
    }

    result = usersWeight + hamburgerGain;

    return result;
}

double eatPizza(double usersWeight) {
    double result;
    double pizzas = 0.0;
    double pizzaGain = 0.0;
    printf("How many pizza's did you eat?\n");
    scanf("%i", &pizzas);
    flush;
    pizzaGain = pizzas * .075;

    if (pizzas > 2) {
        pizzaGain = pizzaGain + 1;
    }

    result  = usersWeight + pizzaGain;

    return result;
}

double eatCake(double usersWeight) {
    double result;
    double cakesEaten = 0.0;
    double cakeGain = 0.0;
    printf("How many cakes did you eat?\n");
    scanf("%i", &cakesEaten);
    flush;
    cakeGain = cakesEaten * 2;
    result = usersWeight + cakeGain;

    return result;
}

double hardWorkout(double usersWeight) {
    double result;
    double hardWorkoutHours = 0.0;
    double hardWorkoutLoss = 0.0;
    printf("How many hours did you perform a hard workout?\n");
    scanf("%i", &hardWorkoutHours);
    flush;
    hardWorkoutLoss = hardWorkoutHours * 1;

    if (hardWorkoutHours > 2) {
        hardWorkoutLoss = hardWorkoutLoss + 1;
    }

    result = usersWeight - hardWorkoutLoss;

    return result;
}

double mediumWorkout(double usersWeight) {
    double result;
    double mediumWorkoutHours = 0.0;
    double mediumWorkoutLoss = 0.0;
    printf("How many hours did you perform a medium workout?\n");
    scanf("%i", &mediumWorkoutHours);
    flush;
    mediumWorkoutLoss = mediumWorkoutHours * .5;

    if (mediumWorkoutHours > 2) {
        mediumWorkoutLoss = mediumWorkoutLoss + .25;
    }

    result = usersWeight - mediumWorkoutLoss;

    return result;
    }

    double easyWorkout(double usersWeight) {
    double result;
    double easyWorkoutHours = 0.0;
    double easyWorkoutLoss = 0.0;
    printf("How many hours did you perform a easy workout?\n");
    scanf("%i", &easyWorkoutHours);
    flush;
    easyWorkoutLoss = easyWorkoutHours * .025;
    result = usersWeight - easyWorkoutLoss;

    return result;
    }

    /*void weightChecker(double usersWeight) {

    if (usersWeight >= 200 && usersWeight <= 400) 
    {
        printf("You are obese, time to start working out.\n");
    }
    else if (usersWeight >= 150 && usersWeight < 200)
    {
        printf("Your weight is considered heavy, time to cut down on junk food.\n");
    }
    else if (usersWeight >= 125 && usersWeight <150)
    {
        printf("You are fit, keep up the good work.\n");
    }
    else if (usersWeight >= 80 && usersWeight <125)
    {
        printf("You are thin, time to start considering eating more.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You are dead due to improper weight management. Game Over!\n");
        pause;
        exit(0);
    }

    pause;
} */
```

Comment: Please post only relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Well, *how* do they differ? And *why* would it affect the results? That's a [fun] exercise for you to work through!

Comment: how about we reduce the scope of the problem a little bit and focus on only one function for now.

Comment: And don't just tell us that the function doesn't work, but tell us what actually does happen when you run it.  Compiler error?  Runtime Error?  What does the error say? etc.

Comment: +1 On a merrier note: I think it's a rather original program!

Comment: My C is rusty but when you scan %i, and pass in a reference to a double, is that supposed to work?

Comment: The runLoss function returns result but it does not effect the usersWeight variable whereas the eatCake() returns result and it does effect the usersWeight

Comment: I do not get a runtime or a compiler error but if I enter 180 as the starting weight and then go in to eatCake() and enter 3 pieces of cake (2 lbs per cake) than it shows an adjusted weight of 186. When I go in to the runLoss() with a starting weight of 180 and enter 10 miles run, it would either return 180 or 0.0000 depending on my printf % setting

Comment: The frustrating part is that my intro class was taught completely out of c++ and this instructor teaches his intro class out of C. He expects us to know all the syntax for c right off the bat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print a double or a float value you shoud use %f

```
float x;
x = eatNutella();
printf("x is %f\n", x);
```

%d is for decimal values (like int)

Comment: The runLoss function does not return expected value. I have gone through it with the debugger and I can see the variable values are wrong but I cant figure out why. I will change my scanf's to %f but why does my cakeGain function work when it uses %i?

Comment: Oh, cakeGain uses whole numbers even though they are assigned to be doubles. Let me change it and see.

Comment: you must use the format declaration that fit the variable type, not the variable content!

Comment: I originally had type int setup for variables where the user would be entering whole numbers but my instructor told me to make the values all doubles because I would be doing double math the values at some point. When I canged milesRan to an int, I got a really large odd number return.

Comment: same problem with scanf. you are specifing integer format with %i but you are storing the resoult into a double. use scanf with %f. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Comment: I isolated the double enterWeight() function and changed both the scanf and printf to %f but now when I enter 180, I get a return of 0.0000 instead of 180. That was one of the only functions that originally worked.

Comment: That seems to be working but when I enter a weight of 180 I get a starting weight of 180.000000. When I choose runLoss() and enter 10 miles ran (@ .005 per mile), I get 179.949997 instead of 179.950000. I guess I can change the precision to get correct result, but that is the first time in hours that I got the runLoss() to work.

Comment: I fixed it with (%.2f). Paolo, you are the man. One function down, three more to go. Thank You!!!

Comment: it IS working. You get 180.000000 because all available decimal digits are printed too. If you want only one decimal digit use printf("%.1f",x);

Comment: I dont really know why %f works only with floats in this case and not doubles but I will take it how I can get it

Comment: I don't know too; maybe a misbehaviour of the compiler. Look here http://codepad.org/ELrmfbBC %f works fine with double.